# Как запустить рисовку canvas и остановить ее при нажатии на кнопки

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

```js
let canvas, ctx, w, h;
let mousePos;
let min;
let max;
let maxspeed;
// an empty array!
let balls = [];
//let player = {};
const player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  color: "red"
};

function init() {
  // called AFTER the page has been loaded
  canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  // often useful
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;

  // important, we will draw with this object
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // create balls
  //player = createPlayer(document.getElementById("Size").value);
  balls = createBalls(document.getElementById("bquantity").value);

  // add a mousemove event listener to the canvas
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved);

  // ready to go !
  mainLoop();
}
function stopinit() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}
Start.addEventListener("click", init);
Stop.addEventListener("click", stopinit);

function createBalls(n) {
  // empty array
  min = document.getElementById("min").value;
  max = document.getElementById("max").value;
  maxspeed = document.getElementById("maxspeed").value;
  const ballArray = [];

  // create n balls
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const b = {
      x: w / 2,
      y: h / 2,
      radius: (min + max) * Math.random(), // between ... and ..
      speedX: maxspeed * Math.random(), // between ... and ...+10
      speedY: maxspeed * Math.random(), // between -5 and ...+10
      color: getARandomColor()
    };
    // add ball b to the array
    ballArray.push(b);
  }
  // returns the array full of randomly created balls
  return ballArray;
}

function mouseMoved(evt) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  // necessary work in the canvas coordinate system
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function movePlayerWithMouse() {
  if (mousePos !== undefined) {
    player.x = mousePos.x;
    player.y = mousePos.y;
  }
}

function mainLoop() {
  // 1 - clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  // draw the ball and the player
  drawFilledRectangle(player);
  drawAllBalls(balls);
  drawNumberOfBallsAlive(balls);

  // animate the ball that is bouncing all over the walls
  moveAllBalls(balls);

  movePlayerWithMouse();

  // ask for a new animation frame
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

// Collisions between rectangle and circle
function circRectsOverlap(x0, y0, w0, h0, cx, cy, r) {
  let testX = cx;
  let testY = cy;
  if (testX < x0) testX = x0;
  if (testX > x0 + w0) testX = x0 + w0;
  if (testY < y0) testY = y0;
  if (testY > y0 + h0) testY = y0 + h0;
  return (cx - testX) * (cx - testX) + (cy - testY) * (cy - testY) < r * r;
}

function getARandomColor() {
  const colors = ["red", "blue", "cyan", "purple", "pink", "green", "yellow"];
  // a value between 0 and color.length-1
  // Math.round = rounded value
  // Math.random() a value between 0 and 1
  let colorIndex = Math.round((colors.length - 1) * Math.random());
  let c = colors[colorIndex];

  // return the random color
  return c;
}

function drawNumberOfBallsAlive(balls) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";

  if (balls.length === 0) {
    ctx.fillText("YOU WIN!", 20, 30);
  } else {
    ctx.fillText(balls.length, 20, 30);
  }
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawAllBalls(ballArray) {
  ballArray.forEach(function(b) {
    drawFilledCircle(b);
  });
}

function moveAllBalls(ballArray) {
  // iterate on all balls in array
  ballArray.forEach(function(b, index) {
    // b is the current ball in the array
    b.x += b.speedX;
    b.y += b.speedY;
    testCollisionBallWithWalls(b);
    testCollisionWithPlayer(b, index);
  });
}

function testCollisionWithPlayer(b, index) {
  if (
    circRectsOverlap(
      player.x,
      player.y,
      player.width,
      player.height,
      b.x,
      b.y,
      b.radius
    )
  ) {
    // we remove the element located at index
    // from the balls array
    // splice: first parameter = starting index
    //         second parameter = number of elements to remove
    balls.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function testCollisionBallWithWalls(b) {
  // COLLISION WITH VERTICAL WALLS ?
  if (b.x + b.radius > w) {
    // the ball hit the right wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedX = -b.speedX;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.x = w - b.radius;
  } else if (b.x - b.radius < 0) {
    // the ball hit the left wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedX = -b.speedX;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.x = b.radius;
  }

  // COLLISIONS WTH HORIZONTAL WALLS ?
  // Not in the else as the ball can touch both
  // vertical and horizontal walls in corners
  if (b.y + b.radius > h) {
    // the ball hit the right wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedY = -b.speedY;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.y = h - b.radius;
  } else if (b.y - b.radius < 0) {
    // the ball hit the left wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedY = -b.speedY;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.Y = b.radius;
  }
}

function drawFilledRectangle(r) {
  // GOOD practice: save the context, use 2D trasnformations
  ctx.save();

  // translate the coordinate system, draw relative to it
  ctx.translate(r.x, r.y);

  ctx.fillStyle = r.color;
  // (0, 0) is the top left corner of the monster.

  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height);

  // GOOD practice: restore the context
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawFilledCircle(c) {
  // GOOD practice: save the context, use 2D trasnformations
  ctx.save();

  // translate the coordinate system, draw relative to it
  ctx.translate(c.x, c.y);

  ctx.fillStyle = c.color;
  // (0, 0) is the top left corner
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, c.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();

  // GOOD practice: restore the context
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  border: 4px solid rgb(88, 73, 73);
  background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
}

li {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <p><label>Player's size :</label>
          <input type="text" size="3" id="Size" />
        <p>
            <label>Max Ball speed : </label
              ><input type="text" size="3" id="maxspeed" /> 
        </p>
<p> <label>Ball quantity :</label
  ><input type="text" size="3" id="bquantity" name="bquantity" /></p>
        <p>
            <label>Balls' size : </label>
            <ul>
              <li><label>Min :</label><input type="number" size="3" id="min" /></li>
              <li><label>Max :</label><input type="number" size="3" id="max" /></li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        <div class="menu">
            <button id="Start">Start</button>
            <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно за счет переменной:

```
let inProgress;

function init() {
  inProgress = true;
  ...
}

function stopinit() {
  inProgress = false; 
}

function mainLoop() {
  ...
  if(inProgress){
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); 
  }else {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }  
}
```

```js
let canvas, ctx, w, h;
let mousePos;
let min;
let max;
let maxspeed;
// an empty array!
let balls = [];
//let player = {};
const player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  color: "red"
};

let inProgress; // !!

function init() {
  inProgress = true;
  // called AFTER the page has been loaded
  canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  // often useful
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;

  // important, we will draw with this object
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // create balls
  //player = createPlayer(document.getElementById("Size").value);
  balls = createBalls(document.getElementById("bquantity").value);

  // add a mousemove event listener to the canvas
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved);

  // ready to go !
  mainLoop();
}
function stopinit() {
  inProgress = false; // !!
}
Start.addEventListener("click", init);
Stop.addEventListener("click", stopinit);

function createBalls(n) {
  // empty array
  min = document.getElementById("min").value;
  max = document.getElementById("max").value;
  maxspeed = document.getElementById("maxspeed").value;
  const ballArray = [];

  // create n balls
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const b = {
      x: w / 2,
      y: h / 2,
      radius: (min + max) * Math.random(), // between ... and ..
      speedX: maxspeed * Math.random(), // between ... and ...+10
      speedY: maxspeed * Math.random(), // between -5 and ...+10
      color: getARandomColor()
    };
    // add ball b to the array
    ballArray.push(b);
  }
  // returns the array full of randomly created balls
  return ballArray;
}

function mouseMoved(evt) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  // necessary work in the canvas coordinate system
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function movePlayerWithMouse() {
  if (mousePos !== undefined) {
    player.x = mousePos.x;
    player.y = mousePos.y;
  }
}

function mainLoop() {
  // 1 - clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  // draw the ball and the player
  drawFilledRectangle(player);
  drawAllBalls(balls);
  drawNumberOfBallsAlive(balls);

  // animate the ball that is bouncing all over the walls
  moveAllBalls(balls);

  movePlayerWithMouse();

  // ask for a new animation frame
  
  if(inProgress){
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); 
  }else {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }  
}

// Collisions between rectangle and circle
function circRectsOverlap(x0, y0, w0, h0, cx, cy, r) {
  let testX = cx;
  let testY = cy;
  if (testX < x0) testX = x0;
  if (testX > x0 + w0) testX = x0 + w0;
  if (testY < y0) testY = y0;
  if (testY > y0 + h0) testY = y0 + h0;
  return (cx - testX) * (cx - testX) + (cy - testY) * (cy - testY) < r * r;
}

function getARandomColor() {
  const colors = ["red", "blue", "cyan", "purple", "pink", "green", "yellow"];
  // a value between 0 and color.length-1
  // Math.round = rounded value
  // Math.random() a value between 0 and 1
  let colorIndex = Math.round((colors.length - 1) * Math.random());
  let c = colors[colorIndex];

  // return the random color
  return c;
}

function drawNumberOfBallsAlive(balls) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";

  if (balls.length === 0) {
    ctx.fillText("YOU WIN!", 20, 30);
  } else {
    ctx.fillText(balls.length, 20, 30);
  }
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawAllBalls(ballArray) {
  ballArray.forEach(function(b) {
    drawFilledCircle(b);
  });
}

function moveAllBalls(ballArray) {
  // iterate on all balls in array
  ballArray.forEach(function(b, index) {
    // b is the current ball in the array
    b.x += b.speedX;
    b.y += b.speedY;
    testCollisionBallWithWalls(b);
    testCollisionWithPlayer(b, index);
  });
}

function testCollisionWithPlayer(b, index) {
  if (
    circRectsOverlap(
      player.x,
      player.y,
      player.width,
      player.height,
      b.x,
      b.y,
      b.radius
    )
  ) {
    // we remove the element located at index
    // from the balls array
    // splice: first parameter = starting index
    //         second parameter = number of elements to remove
    balls.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function testCollisionBallWithWalls(b) {
  // COLLISION WITH VERTICAL WALLS ?
  if (b.x + b.radius > w) {
    // the ball hit the right wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedX = -b.speedX;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.x = w - b.radius;
  } else if (b.x - b.radius < 0) {
    // the ball hit the left wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedX = -b.speedX;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.x = b.radius;
  }

  // COLLISIONS WTH HORIZONTAL WALLS ?
  // Not in the else as the ball can touch both
  // vertical and horizontal walls in corners
  if (b.y + b.radius > h) {
    // the ball hit the right wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedY = -b.speedY;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.y = h - b.radius;
  } else if (b.y - b.radius < 0) {
    // the ball hit the left wall
    // change horizontal direction
    b.speedY = -b.speedY;

    // put the ball at the collision point
    b.Y = b.radius;
  }
}

function drawFilledRectangle(r) {
  // GOOD practice: save the context, use 2D trasnformations
  ctx.save();

  // translate the coordinate system, draw relative to it
  ctx.translate(r.x, r.y);

  ctx.fillStyle = r.color;
  // (0, 0) is the top left corner of the monster.

  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height);

  // GOOD practice: restore the context
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawFilledCircle(c) {
  // GOOD practice: save the context, use 2D trasnformations
  ctx.save();

  // translate the coordinate system, draw relative to it
  ctx.translate(c.x, c.y);

  ctx.fillStyle = c.color;
  // (0, 0) is the top left corner
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, c.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();

  // GOOD practice: restore the context
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  border: 4px solid rgb(88, 73, 73);
  background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
}

li {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <p><label>Player's size :</label>
          <input type="text" size="3" id="Size" />
        <p>
            <label>Max Ball speed : </label
              ><input type="text" size="3" id="maxspeed" /> 
        </p>
<p> <label>Ball quantity :</label
  ><input type="text" size="3" id="bquantity" name="bquantity" /></p>
        <p>
            <label>Balls' size : </label>
            <ul>
              <li><label>Min :</label><input type="number" size="3" id="min" /></li>
              <li><label>Max :</label><input type="number" size="3" id="max" /></li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        <div class="menu">
            <button id="Start">Start</button>
            <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: задачу решил немного по другому, с помощью cancelAnimationFrame, но ваш ответ также подходит